# How to set charset in c++, i am beginner

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, console, setlocale

Can somebody help me? I am beginner in c++, and i don't know why don't works
So i want to use Hungarian characters [ ÁŰŐÚÓÜÍ ] I tried to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu_HU.utf8");`  `setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu_HU.ISO88592");` and `setlocale(LC_ALL,"hun");` but none of them works.

Sorry for my bad english guys :I

My full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

HANDLE con = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
void jatekmenet();
int vegeredmeny();
void init();
void validation();
void rolling();
int balance=50000,huzas,radm,sec,last,bet;
char color;
int table[15];
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu_HU.utf8");
    system("cls");
    srand(time(0));
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 15);
    cout<<"Udvozollek a programban! Ez egy roulett program!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Kerem valasszon opciot! "<<endl;
    cout<<"[0] Inditas"<<endl;
    cout<<"[1] Informacio"<<endl;
    cout<<"[2] Kilepes"<<endl;
    char opc = 'k';
    cin>>opc;
    if(opc=='0') {
        jatekmenet();
    } else if(opc=='1') {
        system("cls");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 240);
        cout<<"Informacio: A jatek ";
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 241);
        cout<<"50.000 ";
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 240);
        cout<<"coinnal kezdodik!"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ha bejon a FEKETE vagy a PIROS akkor megduplazodik a feltett penzed, ha pedig ZOLD jon meg 14 szeresedik a tet!"<<endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 79);
        cout<<"Abban az esetben ha nem jott ossze a tipped, elveszted a feltett penzedet!"<<endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 15);
        Sleep(7000);
        main();
    } else if(opc=='2') {

    }
    return 0;
}
void init() {
    for(int i=0;i<=15;i++) {
        table[i]=rand()%13+1;
    }
    rolling();
}
void jatekmenet() {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Add meg a tetet: ";
    cin>>bet;
    balance = balance - bet;
    cout<<"A jatek tete: "<<bet<<" Melyik szint szeretned megrakni? [P/F/Z]"<<endl;
    cin>>color;
    if(color=='P') {
        cout<<"A megtett szin a Piros (A penz duplazodhat | Esely: Medium)"<<endl;
    } else if(color=='F') {
        cout<<"A megtett szin a Fekete (A penz duplazodhat | Esely: Medium)"<<endl;
    } else if(color=='Z') {
        cout<<"A megtett szin a Zöld (A penz 14szeresedhet | Esely: Kicsi)"<<endl;
    }
    Sleep(3000);
    sec = 10;
    while(sec>=0) {
        system("cls");
        cout<<sec<<" Masodperc mulva indul a porgetes!"<<endl;
        sec = sec-1;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    init();
}
void rolling() {
    for(int i=0;i<=15;i++) {
        system("cls");
        last = table[i];
        cout<<"--> "<<table[i]<<" <--";
        Sleep(200);
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 10);
    cout<<" lett a nyertes szam!";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(con, 15);
    validation();
}
void validation() {
    if(last==0) {
        if(color=='Z') {
            balance = balance+(14*bet);
            cout<<"  (Zöld 14x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Nyertel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        } else {
            balance = balance-bet;
            cout<<"  (Zöld 14x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Elvesztettel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        }
    } else if(last%2==0 && last!=0) {
        if(color=='P') {
            balance = balance+(2*bet);
            cout<<"  (Piros 2x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Nyertel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        } else {
            balance = balance-bet;
            cout<<"  (Piros 2x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Elvesztettel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        }
    } else if(last%2!=0) {
        if(color=='F') {
            balance = balance+(2*bet);
            cout<<"  (Fekete 2x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Nyertel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        } else {
            balance = balance-bet;
            cout<<"  (Fekete 2x)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Vesztettel "<<bet<<" coint)";
        }
    } else {
        cout<<" (Szar van a palacsintába)! Penzed: "<<balance<<" (Nyertel "<<bet<<" coint)";
    }
    Sleep(5000);
    jatekmenet();
}
```

Comment: If windows is set to hungarian you probably just need to save your source file with the ISO88592 encoding and it'll work. If you aren't using hungarian windows then you'll probably struggle to get it to work without using `wcout` and wide strings (prefix all your string literals with `L`)

Comment: Thanks man! Works fine with ISO88592 the problem was the utf-8 encoding! Have a nice day! :-)